# How parse id with SwiftyJSON swift 4.2 ,why is wrong?

Tags: swifty-json

```
//This JSON {"data":[{"id":288,"eid":16,"admin":true},{"id":289,"eid":16,"admin":false}],"meta":{"count":2}}
```

> Alamofire.request(self.url, headers: header).responseJSON
>   (completionHandler: { response in
>                       statusCode = (response.response?.statusCode)!
>                       if statusCode != 200{
>                       }else{
>                           switch response.result {
>                           case .success( let responseJSON):
>                               let json = JSON(responseJSON)
>                               print(json)
>                               let data = json["data"]
>                               print(data)
>                           case .failure(_):
>                               print("ERROR")
>                           }
>                       }
>                   })
>               }
>           }
>       }

Comment: `count:"2"` should be `"count":"2"` - JSON mandates keys to be double-quoted strings. As it is, that is not valid JSON.

Comment: Ok, error mine. And Now?